# contenate rows based on duplicate column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
ID              State   c1      c2
300000568860    solid   B025    B200
300000568860    solid   K639    
300000010727    solid   F010    F023
300000010727    solid   K010    K002
300000010727    solid   F010    F023
```

If column Id repeats then all rows will come to single line.
Ex

```
ID              state    c1                 c2
300000568860    solid    B025,K639          B200
300000010727    solid    F010,K010          F023,K002
```

Can some one suggest how to do it.
Please note that it is difficult to predict the duplication with in ID column .It can be (1 or 2 or 3)they are dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can any one point me in right direction

Comment: This is a very tricky problem to solve using formulas, especially because of the need to account for duplicate data. I suggest switching to a VBA solution.

Comment: I was able to generate a consolidated list of ID's with this array formula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,"<"&$A$2:$A$6)-SUM(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,F$1:F1)),0))`, but there's no way to `CONCATENATE` arrays without VBA.  So, I'd agree with @JamesMcLeod